# position close imagebutton outside jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I want to put the close imagebutton outside the jquery ui dialog.

This is my code:

Css:

```
 .Close
    {
        position:absolute;
        overflow:auto;
        height:25px;
        width:35px;
        right: -34px;
        top: 3px;
    }
```

And this is Asp.NET code:

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialog ">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancelpopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/quit.png" CssClass="Close"/>
</div>
```

This is JavaScript code:

```
$(function(){
$("#dialog").dialog({
            maxWidth: 600,
            maxHeight: 585,
            height: 450,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manually bind an event to an outside element.

```
$('#btnCancelpopup').click(function () {
     $('#dialog').dialog('close');
}
```

Comment: No , i want the close button to be outside the dialog when it's shown

Comment: But with this solution you could put the "#btnCancelpopup" outside the dialog, and show/hide in your dialogs open event.